# package/packagescan tag in Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

Trying to load the routes from .xml file.Instead of using import resource,or "route context ref".

So i wrote a Routebuilder class with following code

`InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("barRoute.xml");
RoutesDefinition routes = context.loadRoutesDefinition(is);
context.addRouteDefinitions(routes.getRoutes());`

and loaded the routes at the time of camelcontext loading.
using 
com.***.Loadroutes

I am able to load routes from xml file in standalone.
But when i deploy the bundle to fuse container,routes are not loading from xml file.

How to use package/packagescan in blurprint/spring to run inside fuse
note :made project as osgi specific bundle and normal bundle(mvn camel:run).

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653322/getresourceasstream-not-loading-resource-in-webapp

Comment: What's the error did you get?

Comment: Hi Willem Jiang ,thanks for the replay and link. I have used <routebuilder ref=""xxx"> instead of packagescan. Now its working in fuse containers